# show the "add another" button when the form is successfully send using codeigniter

Tags: forms, codeigniter

i have this form called news and events, I want that when the form is successfully saved, the table form will hide then the add another button will appear. Im using session set userdata so that when the form is successfully saved the add another button will appear then the table form will hide. my code runs well but the problem is, after it successfully send the add another button will not work here's my controller below

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
session_start();

class News_and_events extends CI_Controller {
  public function __construct(){
      parent::__construct();
      $this->load->library('form_validation');
      $this->load->model('admin_model', 'am');
  }

  public function index(){
    if($this->session->userdata('logged_in')){
      $this->data['title'] = 'News and Events | Spring Rain Global Consultancy Inc Admin Panel';
      $this->data['logout'] = 'Logout';

      $session_data = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');
      $this->data['id'] = $session_data['id'];
      $this->data['username'] = $session_data['username'];

      $this->data['allData'] = $this->am->getAllData();


      $this->load->view('pages/admin_header', $this->data);
      $this->load->view('content/news_and_events', $this->data);
      $this->load->view('pages/admin_footer');
    }else{
      redirect('login', 'refresh');
    }
  }

  public function add(){
    if($this->session->userdata('logged_in')){

      $this->form_validation->set_rules('date', 'Date', 'trim|required|xss_clean');
      $this->form_validation->set_rules('event', 'Event', 'trim|required|xss_clean');
      $this->form_validation->set_rules('description', 'Description', 'trim|required|xss_clean');

      if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE){
         $this->data['title'] = 'News and Events | Spring Rain Global Consultancy Inc Admin Panel';
         $this->data['logout'] = 'Logout';

          $session_data = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');
          $this->data['id'] = $session_data['id'];
          $this->data['username'] = $session_data['username'];
          $this->data['allData'] = $this->am->getAllData();

          $this->load->view('pages/admin_header', $this->data);
          $this->load->view('content/news_and_events', $this->data);
          $this->load->view('pages/admin_footer');

      }else{
        $array = array(
                  'Date' => $this->input->post('date'),
                  'Event' => $this->input->post('event'),
                  'Description' => $this->input->post('description')

                );
        $this->am->saveData($array);
        $this->session->set_userdata('add_another', $array);
        redirect('news_and_events', 'refresh');
      }

    }else{
      redirect('homepage', 'refresh');
    }
  }

}
```

and my views

```
<div class="container" >
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <ul id="nav">
     <li><a href="<?php echo base_url().'homepage'?>" title="Home"><h4>Home</h4></a></li>
     <li><a href="<?php echo base_url().'news-and-events'?>" title="News and Events"><h4>News and Events</h4></a></li>
     <li><a href="" title="Activities"><h4>Activities</h4></a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="starter-template">
      <h1>News And Events</h1>
      <?php if($this->session->set_userdata('add_another')):?>
        <div id="add_another" style="float:left;">
            <input  type="button" value="Add Another" class="btn btn-primary" />
          </div>
       <?php else: ?>
         <form action="<?php echo base_url().'news-and-events/add'?>" method="post">
           <?php echo validation_errors('<div class="error">', '</div>');?>
          <table class="table-striped">
            <tr>
              <td>Date: </td>
              <td><input type="text" id="datepicker" name="date" value="<?php echo set_value('date');?>" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td >Event: </td>
              <td ><input  type="text" name="event" value="<?php echo set_value('event');?>" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td width="20%">Description: </td>
              <td><textarea cols="30" rows="5" name="description" ><?php echo set_value('description');?></textarea></td>
            </tr>
             <tr>
              <td width="20%">&nbsp;</td>
              <td><input type="submit" value="Add" class="btn btn-success" /></td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </form>
        <?php endif; ?>
      <br />
      <br />
      <table class="table" >
        <tr>
          <th>Date</th>
          <th width="51%">Event</th>
          <th>Description</th>
          <th>Options</th>
        </tr>
        <?php foreach($allData as $allData): ?>
        <tr>
          <td><?php echo $allData->Date; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $allData->Event; ?></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
      </table>
    </div>

  </div><!-- /.container -->

<script> 
      var date = new Date();
      var currentMonth = date.getMonth();
      var currentDate = date.getDate();
      var currentYear = date.getFullYear();

      $('#datepicker').datepicker({
        minDate: new Date(currentYear, currentMonth, currentDate),
        dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd"
      });

</script>
```

in my views file ive added there the if else statement  $this->session->set_userdata('add') just below the h1 tag which is news and events this will trigger the statement when the form is successfully saved!

can someone help me figured this out? or how to do this correctly?

any help is much appreciated! thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

istead of this line

```
<?php if($this->session->set_userdata('add_another')):?>
```

use this

```
   <?php if($this->session->userdata('add_another')):?>
```

and in your controller before loading the view add this line

```
  $this->session->set_userdata('add_another',1);
```

Comment: hi but ahm when i tried to click back the session userdata remains how will i able to unset this?

Comment: use `$this->session->unset_userdata('add_another');`

Comment: where will i add that?

Comment: anyways i would recommend using flashdata instead of userdata for this pourpose.. as it gets automatically unset on second page.

Comment: that is a problem because u never know where a user will click and on which controller he is redirected from a page. so i would prefer using flashdata instead of userdata.

Comment: in your controller use `$session_data = $this->session->set_flashdata('logged_in',1);` to set flashdata. in your view use $this->session->flasdata('logged_in') to check data. and u have to write a simple code in ur controller to check if user is redirected to same page the again set the falshdata

Comment: logged_in?? or add_another//

Comment: HI it works now with the flashdata instead of session userdata but ahm can i ask what is 1 in there?

Comment: 1 is the value you are storing in your session variable so when u u write `if ($this->session->flash_data('logged_in'))` which will be same as `if (1)`

Comment: ah okay i see but ahm is it okay if there is no 1 in there?

Comment: no u have to store some value in the variable ...`$this->session->set_userdata()` this function accepts two parameters 1st is variable name and second is its value... u have to pass in some value.

Comment: ahh okay i see thanks for that by the ways its the flashdata not the userdata